# thunderbird 78 do not allow me attach my public key even when the key is imported

Tags: thunderbird

I have different gpg key for each of my email account. After migrating from enigmail to TB78 key manager, I cannot send email as certain identities. I can only send as one of my ids.

looking at the End-To-End Encryption setting, I can see it said: `Thunderbird doesn't have a personal OpenPGP key for xxx@bbb`. However, the tb78's openpgp key manager's key structure panel reports I have that key already, all 3 of them: private, sign and encryption.

I can decrypt the the mail other sent to me with the key of xxx@bbb. So this prove I have that private key in tb78 key manager already. I can also send encrypted mail in tb78 from my other account to xxx@bbb, this proves that the tb78 has my encryption key too.

So why tb78 report that I do not have a key?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out tb78 can not handle offline master key. Use gpg agent as external key agent solve this problem